# The golden ratio in a parabola

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, golden-ratio

It is nice that the golden ratio appears automatically when we are not looking for it. This is what happened to me when I was using GeoGebra and trying to solve a different problem that occurred to me:

Data: $C$ parabola Featured F and L, Point A moving freely on L, Point B represents Muscat-based F on L, Point M represents

Intersection of a F widget with C.

Required: Find the appropriate position for a point A which makes AM=FB.

My solution:
[image]

Was it previously discovered or not?
In any case, how do we prove that?

Comment: I would suggest proving it algebraically.

Comment: Drop a perpendicular from M to L.

Comment: Note that many ratios can be reduced geometrically when we prove that $AM ⊥ BM$

Comment: Are F the focus and L the directrix of C?

Comment: This is very hard to read: the statement uses incomplete sentences, some Geogebra jargon, and I have no idea what "Muscat" is.

Comment: You can blame the Google Translator that I write through, anyway you can dispense with words and just picture and equations

Comment: You might blame Google Translate, but it is up to *you* to put together a coherent and complete question, not Google Translate.

Comment: لا أعرف اللغة الإنجليزية

Answer (score 10):

[image]

*GeoGebra plot with polar equations for the parabola and its directrix. Parameter $p=FB$ has been taken equal to $1$.*

Let us take the focus $F$ of the parabola as the origin and the horizontal line passing through the focus as the reference $x$-axis, in particular for angles.

Let us consider the following polar equations where $\theta := \angle (Fx,FP)$ ($P$ being a generic point on the parabola) :

- parabola's polar equation : $r= -\frac{p}{1-\sin \theta}$
- directrix' AP polar equation : $r= -\frac{p}{\sin \theta}$

With these equations, condition :

$$AM=FB \iff FA-FM=FB$$

can be expressed as :

$$- \frac{p}{1-\sin \theta}+\frac{p}{\sin\theta}-=p$$

Setting $x:=\sin \theta$, and simplifying by $p$ : one gets quadratic equation :

$$x^2+x-1=0$$

whose unique root in interval $[-1,1]$ is

$$x=\sin \theta = \frac{1}{\Phi} = \frac{FB}{FA} \tag{1}$$

(indeed $\theta = \angle BAF$)

Tking the inverse ratio in (1) :

$$\frac{FA}{FB}=\Phi$$

Comment: I suggest you reconsider your solution because geogebra says my conclusion is correct https://www.geogebra.org/m/c8ubfxda

Comment: @زكرياحسناوي don’t always believe to softwares. Use your mind instead.

Comment: Well then, it is impossible for the answer to be 2 because this means that FM = FB and this is not possible because this only happens in the case of the hypochondrium

Comment: I can't withdraw the vote now, try to reconsider the solution and amend it so that I can withdraw the negative vote

Comment: Thank you very much, good job

Comment: Downvoting answers is a reasaonable response to answers that contain errors.

Comment: @MJD I never act so. If you are sure that there is an error in an answer, it means that you have spotted where it is. Therefore a curteous way is first to advise the answerer where is his/her error, then wait a certain time for her/him to correct it, leaving one or two days at least.  Errare humanum est, perseverare diabolicum est.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Draw point $D$ on $AB$ such that $MD\perp AB$.

By similiar triangles, we have

$$\frac{AF}{BF}=\frac{AM}{DM}$$

We are given that $AM=BF$. Since $F$ is the focus and $L$ is the directrix, we have $DM=FM$.

$$\frac{AF}{BF}=\frac{BF}{FM}=\frac{BF}{AF-AM}=\frac{BF}{AF-BF}=\frac{1}{\frac{AF}{BF}-1}$$

$$\left(\frac{AF}{BF}\right)^2-\frac{AF}{BF}-1=0$$

$$\therefore \frac{AF}{BF}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$

Comment: Very nice, it would be good to proceed with proving the rest of the parentage

Comment: @زكرياحسناوي Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "parentage".

Comment: I'd stop the proof after $AF/BF=BF/FM$, because that is the definition of golden ratio.

Comment: Google Translate bothers me to clarify things, what I meant was to prove that $MB/FM=NF/AM=Φ$

Comment: @زكرياحسناوي Your question says "Required: Find the appropriate position for a point $A$ which makes $AM=FB$." But your comment suggests that you actually want more. Now I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for.

Comment: The original question is what was the basis for making the assumptions contained in the equality, the golden ratio has accustomed us that if it appears in a geometrical configuration it will appear many times

Comment: @زكرياحسناوي I'm not sure what you mean by "the basis for making the assumptions contained in the equality". Which equality are you referring to? I think it would help if the question simply said "Given that... show that..."

Comment: @Dan I think with *parentage* OP wants you to verify that the second line of text below their image is correct in all steps/ *equalities*.

Answer (score 3):

Jean Marie and Dan have already proven the first question, in my answer I'll show why all those ratios are equal to each other:
At first we have:

[image]

$\frac{AF}{FB}=\frac{AF}{AM}=Φ$

According to what has been proven.
We could also write:

$\frac{AF}{AM}=\frac{AM}{FM}$

as defined by the Golden Ratio.
So since
$AM=FB$
we can write:

$\frac{FB}{FM}=\frac{AM}{FM}$

Thus, in the triangles $∆AFB,∆BFM$, we have proportional sides and the angle between them is equal ( $\angle AFB=\angle BFM$) Therefore $∆AFB,∆BFM$ They are similar.

From the similarities we write: $AM⊥BM$
Thus, we get three similar right triangles, which gives:

$\frac{AF}{FB}=\frac{FB}{FM}=\frac{AB}{BM}$

It remains only to prove that the ratio $\frac{NF}{AF}$ is equal to them.

I will prove that later.